# Ensure a file does not exist

Tags: windows-7, cmd

I've seen this used to ensure a file does not exist, without causing an error:

```
FOR %%F IN (myfile) DO del %%F
```

I can see it has the advantage over the more usual IF EXISTS method in that it has only one instance of the filename.

But the of FOR is distracting to the unfamiliar reader.

Is there a less distracting method still requiring only one reference?

Comment: If you want to use only code, that "unfamiliar readers" can easily understand - where do you want to stop? Even `dir` (eventually with parameters) might be a challenge to "non-programmers". To explain your code, you can use `REM`

Comment: @Stephan, "where do you want to stop?" Before dir :)

Comment: how about just supressing the errormessage: `del /q myfile 2>nul` ?

Comment: Tthat suppresses /all/ error messages.

Comment: yes, because any error message is distracting to the unfamiliar reader  ;)  How about `>error.txt` instead of `>nul`?

Comment: That too suppresses error messages.

Comment: no, it writes them to a file, where you can analyze them. Also %errorlevel% can help you. It's a great challenge to write a program that everyone can easily understand. You will have to make some compromises.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative, readable, and with only one reference to the real file.

```
set "file=c:\somewhere\file.txt"
if exist "%file%" del "%file%"
```

And the code in the question

```
FOR %%F IN (myfile) DO del %%F
```

does not ensure anything unless *myfile* contains a wildcard. If the file search process in the `for` command determines that there are more than one file, only existing files will be iterated, but without a wildcard, the `for` command will execute the code in the `do` clause and, in this case, it will always try to delete the file.

Comment: Thanks. Note: I think that solution requires a few more lines to make it as safe as the original, given its use of the global 'file'. "And the code in the question ... does not ensure anything unless myfile contains a wildcard." It works here: http://i.imgur.com/S4QIEyg.png . What have I missed?

Comment: @ChrisJJ, As it is written, this is more "secure" than the original code. This only deletes the file if it exist. I don't really understand the "global" term here as each process has its own copy of the environment variables. For your code, have you tried to execute the same code when the file does not exist?

Comment: "this is more "secure" than the original code. This only deletes the file if it exist." So does the original, surely? " I don't really understand the "global" term" Global scope in the script. "For your code, have you tried to execute the same code when the file does not exist?" Sure: http://i.imgur.com/HfoIrY7.png . Does that have a problem?

Comment: @ChrisJJ, it seems we both are talking about different meanings for the same concept. If the behaviour shown in your last capture is acceptable (a error in the `del` operation), why the *"...without causing an error:"* in the original question. Why not just a `del myfile` without the `for`? Without a wildcard in `myfile` the `del` command is always executed. For the `%file%` variable, the usage of a global variable makes the code no less secure, it can have side effects in other parts of the code if you use the variable somewhere else, but for this section of code it makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see your point. The FOR and DEL solutions are the same where the (non-wildcard) file does not exist, in outputting a message and not setting errorlevel. "the usage of a global variable ... can have side effects in other parts of the code" Agreed :)